# Review schema for multiple products on one page

Tags: schema

We're getting awfully confused by the review schema, namely because we're trying to do something apparently novel with it!

Our situation: We have 9 written reviews on a homepage, presented as testimonials. There are 3 categories (`item`s) that these reviews relate to.

For example we have `item`s A, B and C. Displayed in the following format on a page:

```
[A] [C] [A]
[B] [A] [C]
[C] [B] [B]
```

The thing is we don't really wish to design the UX around the arbitrary whims of the schema. For a start the reviews aren't grouped, as you can see (so we can't nest the reviews within an aggregate), and ideally we have no need to display the count anyway (which is a requirement).

- I'm assuming that we can't simply hide the count using CSS without annoying Google.
- Is there a way to display aggregate reviews that aren't grouped in the markup? (i.e. by relating data to other data using names, ids etc.)

Having all of the reviews as individual `hreview`s causes Google's validator to flip a little:

> "Error: No rich snippet will be generated for this data, because it appears to include multiple reviews of an item, but no aggregate review information."

Any one got any ideas? Are we just stuck in a position where we're prevented from providing this rich data?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is simple: use JSON-LD.

All Schema properties support JSON-LD, and the Schema website even provides examples. So you never actually have to display any of the data on the page, as it turns out, it can all be handled by JS.